# What would be a good way to compare read performance between Azure SQL and Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

Trying to make a list of pros and cons between SQL and NoSQL options in Azure.
I'm aware of most of the key conceptual differences between the two options, but there's the all important question of performance.  I keep reading that Cosmos DB has great response speed, but it's repeated so often I'm pretty skeptical.

I'd really like to know how some people compare the performance (in particular the performance of read operations) for the SQL and NoSQL options.

**Edit:**
I'm looking to store very large csvs.
Each has a time stamp column and upto 1000 data columns.
I intend to split each column into it's own document and have a summary document which contains the references to each column containing the data.

**Speed is critical on the read, not the write.**

Comment: It really boils down to what you want to store and retrieve. Wanna elaborate a bit more on the use case?

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely you would get a decisive answer here, as it depends on a LOT of small nuances that don't make it and should not make it to the SO question. That's why there are architects and DBAs - because there are no universal silver bullets. If you want to know what works better, then you should choose which exact scenarios you want top optimize, set performance goals, draw red lines and test it out.

Some considerations:

- Generate a realistic data set. In both csv file count, size, structure, and on column value distributions, if possible use real data.
- Do test scenarios requiring multiple roundtrips from the same data center - single call latency may be important.
- Generally, SQL is suited for fixed schema and covering indexes in SQL are fast as well. Consider which queries have to be fast and how would you model the 1000 columns in DB to meet your querying need? Can you write covering indexes to your queries?
- CosmosDB is easier should the structure be varying a lot. Are new columns popping up at random times?
- CosmosDB has automatic/default indexing. It may be important for maintance/dev point of view.
- Consider your team skillset. If performance is of utmost importance then picking a familiar mindset and tech stack may help you avoid costly design mistakes. Especially if your budget/deadlines do not allow rewrites.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to store documents then Cosmos DB will show better performance. For relational databases that do not need to store documents then Azure SQL Database will show better performance.

More than just performance, do not forget the ACID properties Azure SQL Database offers for transactions. You can work around Cosmos DB to make it confer to some of the ACID properties but it will hurt Cosmos DB performance.

Comment: There's really no way to make any performance conclusions without seeing specific data modeling and query use cases.